# Why are Christoffels vanishing depending on choice of basis (xAct)?

Tags: xact

Hi all (probably Jose),

I am not sure if I am misunderstanding some fundamental GR topic or if I am using the package wrong. I would at some point like to contract over the components of the metric tensor which should involve expanding covariant derivatives into Christoffels then into derivatives of the metric (c.f. [my last question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278569/is-there-a-builtin-function-to-expand-covariant-derivatives-in-terms-of-the-metr)). I then assume that I would need to have my elements expressed in a specific basis, say cartesian for ease. So, the way I call elements changes from `u[-a]` to `u[{-a,-cartesian}]`.

So, I'm a little confused though when I take the covariant derivative of an arbitrary vector and depending on using or not using a basis get different answers. Consider the following:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
<< xAct`xCoba`
$PrePrint = ScreenDollarIndices
DefManifold[M,4,{a,b,c,d,e,f,i,j,k,m,n,p,q,r,s}]
DefBasis[cartesian, TangentM, {0,1,2,3}]
DefTensor[u[-a],M]
CovDToChristoffel[PDcartesian[-a][u[b]]]
CovDToChristoffel[PDcartesian[{-a,-cartesian}][u[b]]]
CovDToChristoffel[PDcartesian[-a][u[{b,cartesian}]]]
CovDToChristoffel[PDcartesian[{-a,-cartesian}][u[{b,cartesian}]]]
```

Which gives me 4 output lines of:
[image]

Beyond the color coding to indicate a basis, I don't think I understand why the Christoffels are vanishing in the last two examples. Appologies if this is a fundamental geometry question I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation `u[{a, B}]` in xCoba means the product `u[b] Basis[-b, {a, B}]`, which is a scalar. A vector field is an object with a free abstract index. Basis indices like `{a, B}` do not count. Therefore `u[a]` is a vector field, but `u[{a, B}]` is a scalar field in xCoba. All covariant derivatives of scalar fields coincide, so there is no need to add Christoffel terms when changing from your `PDcartesian` to `PD`.

Similarly, `PD[{-a, -cartesian}][...]` is equivalent to the product `Basis[{-a, -cartesian}, b] PD[-b][...]`.

You may find more standard to use the alternative notation `TensorDerivative[u, PD][a, -b]` instead of `PD[-b][u[a]]`. Now `TensorDerivative[u, PD]` is a tensor with two abstract indices (note the differentiation index is placed last), and you can take components as `TensorDerivative[u, PD][{a, B}, {-b, -B}]` without the basis vectors being differentiated.

Comment: Ahhh, got it! I think I was under the impression that the notation of {a,B} was for eventually indicating what the abstract indexes needed to be summed over in the future by way of a chart. Like indicating that Cartesian would index over x, y, z, t for instance.

It seems obvious now but I kind of assumed that the basis in the notation was basically book keeping until an eventual contraction over the indices. Whereas, this is much more literal in how I should think about it. Thanks Jose! :)